# Verificar se variável é um número inteiro positivo

Tags: linux, variáveis, bash, inteiros

Para verificar se uma variável é um [`integer`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) positivo, estou a recorrer a uma expressão regular:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

id="$1"
regNumTest='^[0-9]+$'

if ! [[ "$id" =~ $regNumTest ]]; then
    echo "Parâmetro #1 deverá ser um inteiro!"
    exit 0
fi
```

Será a melhor abordagem para lidar com esta questão ou podemos simplificar o processo e evitar expressões regulares?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso *sem* recorrer a expressão regular, é avaliar uma expressão com o comando [`expr`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdln_expr.htm), que irá retornar o [código de saída](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) *2* se a expressão for inválida (por exemplo, *letras*), *3* se ocorrer algum erro, ou *0* se a operação for bem sucedida.

Para verificar se é um número inteiro positivo, é usado o operador [`gt`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) (é maior do que).

```sh
#!/bin/bash

id=$1;

if expr "$id" + 0  > /dev/null 2>&1 && [ "$id" -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "$id é um inteiro positivo"
else
    echo "$id não é inteiro positivo"
fi
```

Evitar o uso de expressões regulares pode não ser uma boa ideia, a não ser que você precise fazer a mesma tarefa em diversos sistemas onde a sintaxe, o motor, seja incompatível uns com os outros.

No artigo abaixo aborda esse assunto mais profundamente:

- [Unix Incompatibility Notes: Regular Expression Libraries](http://unixpapa.com/incnote/regex.html)

Answer (score 5):

Esta é uma [alternativa que eu vi no SOzão](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3951175), que eu gostei por ser mais "portável":

```
case $string in
    ''|*[!0-9]*) echo bad ;;
    *) echo good ;;
esac
```

Achei pertinente postar por não ser só mais uma variação de *regex*, como várias que eu vi.

Comment: +1 Efetivamente uma alternativa, embora num modelo um pouco diferente do colocado na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

```
if [[ $var = ?(+|-)+([0-9]) ]] ; then 
echo "$var é um numero"
else
echo "$var não é um numero"
fi
```

Tem essa maneira também.

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o método do @stderr é o mais simples por se valer diretamente do status de saída do comando 'expr', além de ser portátil. Simplificando mais um pouco:

```
[ `expr "$var" + 0 2>&-` ] && [ $var -gt 0 ] && echo 'Número inteiro positivo'
```

'2>&-' suprime a saída de erro, como 2>/dev/null. Nesse caso o comando 'test' não precisa do 'if'.

Answer (score 0):

Eu vou usar uma abordagem diferente, eu vou usar um script em Pyton dentro do Shell Script.

O objetivo não é ser melhor ou mais rápido, tanto que as outras respostas indiscutivelmente  são boas, e sim mostrar uma possibilidade de integração entre o Shell e sua linguagem de programação favorita e resolver o problema proposto segundo os parâmetros especificados.

O algorítimo é simples:

```
Verifique o tipo do primeiro parâmetro de entrada...
     ...se for inteiro retorna Verdadeiro.
     ...se não for inteiro falso retorna Falso.
```

Então o script ficou assim:

```
#!/bin/bash

t=$1


{  echo 'print(type(' $t ') is int)'; } | python -u
```